# Exercise 1.1.7 of Dummit and foote . Is $G$ a group?

Tags: group-theory

This question is from "Abstract Algebra" by Dummit and Foote , third edition , page 21 , exercise 1.1.7 .

> Let $G = \{ x \in \mathbb R | 0 \leq x < 1 \}$ and for $x,y \in G$ let $x*y$ be the fractional part of $x + y$. (i.e, $x*y = x + y - [x + y]$ where  $[a]$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $a$).Prove that $*$ is a well defined binary operation on $G$ and that $G$ is an abelian group under $*$ (called the *real number mod $1$*)

In that exercise , I am asked to prove that $G$ is a group . However , I could not find the identity of the group at all . $0$ seems to not be the identity , because .

If $x \in G$ then $x*0 = 0*x = x + 0 - [x + 0] = x - [x] = x - x = 0$

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please type the question. Everybody does not have access to the book

Comment: @Clayton ok I will do it .

Comment: Thank you for writing out the question, Prithu!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $[x]$ is the greatest integer function. So $[x] = 0$ for all $x \in G$ as in question. Note that $G$ was the interval $[0, 1)$.

Comment: can you also show me that "all the elements of $G$ has inverses"?

Comment: @Prithubiswas: You want to show that given any $x \in G$, there's some $y$ such that $x + y - [x + y] = 0$ or $$x + y = [x + y].$$ Do you know when a real number (here $x + y$) is equal to the greatest integer below it?

Comment: @Prithubiswas Another hint, Which are the integers you can get with the sum of $x+y$?